# BeautifulSoup: find all tags with a certain attribute, not value

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I want to download a file from a website using BeautifulSoup. In order to retrieve the URL, I need to access an `a` tag with a `download` attribute. I know I can filter tags by attribute by passing a `dict` to `BeautifulSoup.find` or `BeautifulSoup.find_all`, but I don't know how to deal with attributes that do not hold a value. How can I do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your question already has an answer on SO. I just wanted to answer for a case where it should either be empty or a pattern

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re
html="""
<div>
<p data="123"></p>
<p data="567"></p>
<p data=""></p>
</div>
"""
soup = BeautifulSoup(html,'lxml')
# get all tags with that attribute
p_list=soup.findAll("p", data=True)
print(p_list)
# get  all tags with attribute value either empty or a particular pattern
p_list=soup.findAll("p", {"data":re.compile("^$|123")})
print(p_list)
```

Output

```
[<p data="123"></p>, <p data="567"></p>, <p data=""></p>]
[<p data="123"></p>, <p data=""></p>]
```